# How to place the exact value of a chart on top of it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

[I'm saying something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1GFJ.png)

I just want to add the values of mean_Bluebook on top of the chart like the example above

Here's my code so far

```
teste <- Claim.Data %>%
    group_by(MAX_EDUC) %>%
    summarise(mean_Bluebook = mean(BLUEBOOK))

options(scipen = 999)
ggplot(teste, 
       aes(x = MAX_EDUC,y=mean_Bluebook )) + 
    geom_bar(color = "grey", fill = "lightgreen",stat="identity") +
    ggtitle("Preço médio do veículo por nível de escolaridade") +
    xlab("Nível de escolaridade") +
    ylab("Preço médio") +
    theme(legend.position="none", 
          plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `geom_text` and include `label` in `aes`. Using `mtcars` as an example dataset :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

teste <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(mean_Bluebook = mean(mpg))


ggplot(teste, 
       aes(x = cyl,y=mean_Bluebook, label = round(mean_Bluebook, 2))) + 
  geom_bar(color = "grey", fill = "lightgreen",stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Preço médio do veículo por nível de escolaridade") +
  xlab("Nível de escolaridade") +
  ylab("Preço médio") +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12)
  )
```

[image]